# Determine the entity manager for a given object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a web application that uses multiple entity managers. Im wondering if its possible to determine which entity manager is managing a particular object.

In my voters im given the object from there i need to get that objects entity manager so that i can check other objects managed by the same manager to verify access.

app/config/config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                ...
            second_connection:
                ...
```

if the object is managed by the default connection then i need to check and make sure the current user has access to that object in that connections "ACL" tables. OR if its managed by the second_connection i need to check that connections "ACL" tables.

I have looked all over for how to do this but cant seem to find it. If it exists i would image it would be something like:

src/Namespace/Bundle/Resources/config/services.yml:

```
services:
    security.access.report_bundle_voter:
        class:      Namespace\Bundle\Security\Voter
        public:     false
        arguments: ["@doctrine"]
        tags:
            - { name: security.voter }
```

src/Namespace/Bundle/Security/Voter.php:

```
...
class Voter
{
    protected $doctrine;

    public function __construct($doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    ...    

    public function vote(...)
    {
        //Would return an instance of the entity manager responsible for that object
        $em = $this->doctrine->determineManger($object);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging through doctrines source api a little more i found a working solution for this. The entity manager has a method [contains($entity)](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#696-707) that will check if the given entity manager manages that entity.

So from there since i didnt know which manager it was all i needed to do was get a list of all of the available managers iterate through them and check if they contain the $entity. If they did then i would set that as the entity manager for the voter.

src/Namespace/Bundle/Resources/config/services.yml:

```
services:
    security.access.report_bundle_voter:
        class:      Namespace\Bundle\Security\Voter
        public:     false
        arguments: ["@doctrine"]
        tags:
            - { name: security.voter }
```

src/Namespace/Bundle/Security/Voter.php:

```
class Voter implements VoterInterface
{
    protected $doctrine;
    protected $em;

    public function __construct($doctrine){
        $this->doctrine=$doctrine;
    }

    public function init($object)
    {
        //Gets all the known connections
        foreach($this->doctrine->getConnections() as $connName => $connInfo){
            //Initializes the EntityManager for this connection
            $em = $this->doctrine->getManager($connName);
            //Checks if this is the EntityManager that is managing the given object
            if($em->contains($object)){
                $this->em = $em;
            }
        }
    }
}
```